# When I set geometry to origin my character's head gets messed up

Tags: modifiers, objects

[image: Original character]

I wanted my character to align down to 3D cursor. When I set origin to Geometry to origin my character's head gets messed up. Please help.

[image: Character after transform]

Comment: Probably this has to do with modifiers added to the object, e.g. Armature or if the head object is parented to another one. The question can have multiple solutions depending on exact case

Comment: "*When I set origin to Geometry*" are you sure what you want is not *Origin to 3D cursor*?

Comment: You cannot change the geometry or the origin point after riggind.

Answer (score 1):

In edit mode press <kbd>TAB</kbd>: select the botom faces from the foots
[image: selecting faces from foots]
press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and click **cursor to selected**
[image: cursor to selected]
press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to set object mode, then press <kbd>T</kbd> to show transform panel and go to set origin and click **set origin to 3D cursor**
[image: set origin to 3D cursor]

**Make sure you don't have another object select** pressing <kbd>A</kbd> to select everything and deselect everything.

Finally select the object and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and click **selection to cursor(offset)**